# How to get several documents by multiple ids that referencing other collections?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a table A, which stores companyId. I need to query table B by the array of companyIds and where `isActive == true`. The problem is that there might be more documents than just 30.

So the only solution I see is to loop code like this

```
const query = db.collection("B")
  .where("companyId", "in", companyIds)
  .where("isActive", "==", true);
```

But is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore only allows you to perform queries for which it can guarantee the performance, no matter the number of documents it needs to consider. The API imposes a limit of maximum of 30 items in an `in` query (and a maximum of 30 disjunctions across all conditions), because it can't guarantee the performance for an even larger number of conditions.

---

The typical workaround (as is always the case when using NoSQL databases) is to change your data model to allow the use-case. For example: what do those 30+ companies have in common that makes you want to select them? E.g. if these are all companies in the same region, or companies with a specific minimum revenue, or who have a specific item in stick, you could store that specific information in the `B` documents - and query on that field.

If you're new to such NoSQL data modeling, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching the excellent [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) video series.